# Is there a better way to write this code? -- Chaining HTTP requests using Promises in NodeJS - Using Await/Async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

I am using NodeJS and Express, Dynamically generating HTTP on a web-page by querying a Database. The page will load elements by going through a MongoDB collection and filling element attributes and content with various properties within the database. PUG/Jade allowed for iterating through the returned Database JSON to generate elements

At first I only needed to query a single collection, but ran into trouble when I needed to look at two or more.

I was chaining callbacks but the data from the first query got stuck in the first closure. I switched to the handy request-promise framework on Github (https://github.com/request/request-promise)

I used .then() clauses, but I was still losing the returned value. I thought I could run res.render twice, but It doesn't allow me to generate partial webpages if the second database query is still undefined.

```
router.get('/main', authorize.adminRequired, function(req, res, next) {
    rp.get({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/menus'
    }, function(err, response, menuItems) {
            console.log(menuItems); 
            res.render('index', {menu: menuItems}) //PUG error, PUG variable "history" is undefined
    }).then(rp.get({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/transactions'   
    }, function(err, response, transactions, menuItems) { //menuItems is now Undefined
    console.log(transactions);
    return res.render('index', {menu: JSON.parse(menuItems), history: JSON.parse(menuItems)});
    }));
});
```

I managed to change the code to make it work. The following code seems to be OK. But is there a better way to writing this out using await, and passing that value, instead of chaining these functions as new variables? I don't really know how to use Promises that well yet.

```
router.get('/main', authorize.adminRequired, function(req, res, next) {
    var getMenuItems = rp.get({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/menus'
        }, function(err, response, menuItems) {
            console.log(menuItems);
            return menuItems;
    });

    getMenuItems.then(function(result){
        rp.get({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/transactions'   
        }, function(err, response, transactions) {
            console.log(transactions);
            return res.render('index', {menu: JSON.parse(result), history: JSON.parse(transactions)});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `}).then(rp.get({` well, that's wrong for a start

Comment: Yes, that was an example of the code when it was not functioning. But I'm not entirely sure why - can't I just keep chaining rp, isn't that the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this piece of code

```
}).then(rp.get({
```

is wrong, because .then accepts 1 (or two) arguments, but silently ignores them (i.e. no error is produced) if they are not a **function**

using .then like you do, you are passing the *result of calling* `rp.get` - which is a Promise, not a function

So, proper use of request-promise:

```
router.get('/main', authorize.adminRequired, function(req, res, next) {
    rp.get({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/menus'
    })
    .then(menuItems => rp.get({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/transactions'}).then(transactions => ({transactions, menuItems})))
    .then(({transactions, menuItems}) => {
        // now do whatever with transactions and menuItems
    })
});
```

using async/await

```
router.get('/main', authorize.adminRequired, async function(req, res, next) {
    let menuItems = await rp.get({url: 'http://localhost:3000/menus'});
    let transactions = await rp.get({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/transactions'});
    // now do whatever with transactions and menuItems
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great, much cleaner than my code.

Comment: I used arrow (`=>`) functions, so, I hope it's still readable for you, I figured since you asked about `async/await` then you'd be familiar with `=>`

Comment: That seems to make the code a lot more concise and reduce redundancy. `.then(menuItems => rp.get({})` is basically equivalent to `.then(function(menuItems) { rp.get({}) })`, right?

Comment: no ... add a return before `rp.get` and you've got it

Answer (score 0):

Since your two `requests` don't depend on each other you can take advantage of `Promise.all()` which will let you request them in parallel rather than sequentially -- and make the code simpler too:

```
router.get('/main', authorize.adminRequired, function(req, res, next) {        
    Promise.all([
            rp.get('http://localhost:3000/menus'),
            rp.get('http://localhost:3000/transactions')
        ])
        .then(([menus, transactions]) => {
            // now you have menus and transaciotns
            res.render(/* use menus and transactions */ )
        })
})
```

Comment: you're right, but the use of `chaining` in the title suggests one after the other :p

Comment: @JaromandaX -- yes, of course, just though I'd add it as an alternative. I think both are nice.